# Crawler4j visits only seeds URLs

Tags: java, web-crawler, crawler4j

I'm using `crawler4j` to crawl rottentomatoes website to extract structured data.
I have setup everything and with default urls given in example on project home page, everything works, but when I put my own seeds, application only visits URLs that I have given it. Did I miss something?

Answer (score 1):

The most common error is that the shouldVisit method always returns false, therefore the crawler only visits the seed urls.